# How make a app in android that shows the hardware specifications of a device

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I have tried make a app in Android that show the hardware specifications of a device, example:

***Processor: Quad Core 1.2 Ghz***

***1 GB Memory RAM***

***8 GB Storage***

***Android Version 4.4***

Would someone help me to find a library that allows me do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
Log.i("ManuFacturer :", Build.MANUFACTURER);
Log.i("Board : ", Build.BOARD);
Log.i("Display : ", Build.DISPLAY);
```

More info can be found at from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Answer (score 1):

I do not know a library that can extract specific hardware specifications, however, the Facebook Device-Year-Class library can classify devices into 'years' based on Hardware specs:

[Github: Device-Year-Class](https://github.com/facebook/device-year-class)

Additionally, you can look through their code to detect how they get info such as the Max Freq KHz:

```
public static int getCPUMaxFreqKHz() {
int maxFreq = DEVICEINFO_UNKNOWN;
try {
  for (int i = 0; i < getNumberOfCPUCores(); i++) {
    String filename =
        "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu" + i + "/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq";
    File cpuInfoMaxFreqFile = new File(filename);
    if (cpuInfoMaxFreqFile.exists()) {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
      FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(cpuInfoMaxFreqFile);
      try {
        stream.read(buffer);
        int endIndex = 0;
        //Trim the first number out of the byte buffer.
        while (Character.isDigit(buffer[endIndex]) && endIndex < buffer.length) {
          endIndex++;
        }
        String str = new String(buffer, 0, endIndex);
        Integer freqBound = Integer.parseInt(str);
        if (freqBound > maxFreq) {
          maxFreq = freqBound;
        }
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //Fall through and use /proc/cpuinfo.
      } finally {
        stream.close();
      }
    }
  }
  if (maxFreq == DEVICEINFO_UNKNOWN) {
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("/proc/cpuinfo");
    try {
      int freqBound = parseFileForValue("cpu MHz", stream);
      freqBound *= 1000; //MHz -> kHz
      if (freqBound > maxFreq) maxFreq = freqBound;
    } finally {
      stream.close();
    }
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  maxFreq = DEVICEINFO_UNKNOWN; //Fall through and return unknown.
}
return maxFreq;
}
```